# Bot service fails with status code:Forbidden

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, cortana, azure-bot-service

Looks like BOTS which are migrated to Azure as (Bot Channels Registration) are not working. I have hosted them on Azure app service and I see `Forbidden` while accessing from Cortana. However, there is no trace of error while calling bot from MS team. If I change the messaging endpoint to local ngrok I can work with BOT.

I see the following message in Bot Channels Registration in azure portal.

> This bot is migrated from the old Azure Bot Service. You can rollback the migration in order to have access to your old bot before 03/31/2018. After 03/31/2018, the old service will be deprecated.

Is meaning of, old service will be deprecated as if Bot still exist on portal `https://dev.botframework.com/bots` it will be retired? Then, in that case, Bot Channels Registration (migrated) Bot should work.

Any thoughts on why this started happing since last 2 days?

```
SDK Platform: Node.js
SDK Version: V3
Active Channels: MS Teams, Cortana
Deployment Environment: Azure App Service
```

Comment: Could you please restart your bot service and try again once? Is it working in web chat? If still not working please share the bot id with us for further troubleshooting.

Comment: You said there's not trace of the error when calling the bot from MS Teams.  Is the bot replying in Teams or is it just silently failing?